# Joomla password screen I've never seen before. Phishing?

Tags: joomla2.5, phishing

I was doing some minor edits to our site when the screen changed to just a white screen with blue all caps text that says "PLEASE LOG IN TO CONTINUE."  Below that is a box that is labeled "Password."  No other text.  No images.  Nothing.  I've never seen anything like this while working with Joomla.

I am just the person who does minor edits to the site.  I am not a Joomla expert.  I read the Joomla.org forums and posted a query there.  No bites yet.  I don't want to be the loser who gives out the password if this is a Phishing exercise.  I can't log in, obviously, to do any digging around.  The person who set up this site is long gone, so there is no admin to ask.  I compared the source code of the login page to the home page of the site and the header is different.  I don't know if that means anything or not.  I just don't know enough about it.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the "Web Developer" plugin of firefox to check if you just somehow broke your own CSS. This might result in such behavior. While you are at it, you can use it to check where each element displayed came from. Make sure to check the dns entry you get for each domain matches with the IP you are expecting to get it from, in case it is actually your own computer that got infected.

With web developer do "inspect element" on the login boxes and check where the input element wants to send your login data. You can also watch the "Web Console" while reloading the page to check where the sites elements are coming from.

Comment: Ahhhh...THANKS!  That makes enough sense for me to follow and now I see that its an RS Firewall issue.  That still doesn't get me in, but it gets me started.

Answer (score 0):

**This is the RSFirewall password.**

[image: RSFirewall Login]

**You can access it in the admin interface by navigating to :**

1. Components
2. RSFirewall
3. Firewall Configuration
4. Backend Password

**You can remove it in SQL by:**

1. Find the table `_rsfirewall_configuration`
2. Set the field`backend_password_enabled` to `0`
3. Delete the field `backend_password`